# PHP 5 and 7 - json_last_error difference

Tags: php, json, php-7

I'm trying to upgrade one of my PHP apps to PHP7. Everything is working great, except one. I see that `json_last_error()` returns a different value in PHP7.

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($input, true);

print_r(json_last_error());
```

When I make

```
curl 'http://localhost/test.php'  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --compressed
```

PHP 5 returns 0 (JSON_ERROR_NONE)

PHP 7 returns 4 (JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX)

I've looked at the official documentation if there was change, but I could not find any info.

Was there a change for either `json_decode()` or `json_last_error()` function?

Comment: There was a change to `json_decode()`, "*7.0.0 An empty PHP string or value that after casting to string is an empty string (NULL, FALSE) results in JSON syntax error.*"

Comment: @Qirel I think that (with a link to where you're quoting from) would make a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [changelog of `json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#refsect1-function.json-decode-changelog), any "falsy" string-value (meaning empty strings, `null` and `false`) will result in a JSON syntax error. So yes, there was a change in `json_decode()` between PHP 5 and PHP 7. `json_last_error()` has however not changed.

Changelog in 7.0.0 of `json_encode()`:

> An empty PHP string or value that after casting to string is an empty string (NULL, FALSE) results in JSON syntax error.